# Change All Activity Language

Tags: android

I have a settings activity and in this activity I have a button. This button change language. But when I try this this change only settings activity's language. How can I change all activity's language? How can I control language changing in another class?

This is changing values code;

```
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Locale locale = new Locale("en"); //local en
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.dil_degistir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it OK, but you need to "refresh" the first activity to see the changes..

maybe you can start settings activity using startActivityForResult, and when the response arrives to first activity, you can refresh this screen